# Persist simple textfile across app restarts

Tags: swift

I am trying to persist a simple file with:

```
        if let documents = directories.first {
            if let urlDocuments = URL(string: documents) {

                let urlText = urlDocuments.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
                print(urlText)
                do {
                    try text.write(to: urlText, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                    print(text)
                }
                catch {}
                true)

            }
        }
```

but no matter what directory I choose, it saves it in something like

/Users/jaredearl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6D477D99-7741-472D-8D16-4AE6771AF92E/data/Containers/Data/Appli ... file.txt

That tag there changes across restarts and when I use something like:

```
let documents = "/Users/jaredearl/Desktop/"
        if let urlDocuments = URL(string: documents) {

            let urlText = urlDocuments.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
            print(urlText)
            do {
                try text.write(to: urlText, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                print(text)
            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}

        }
```

Then when I try to read the file I get: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

How can I get it to persist across restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift 3.0

You can use same function to read/write in file

```
func storeSyncLog(txtStor:String) {
    let fileName = "a.txt"        
    let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    //If the directory was found, we write a file to it and read it back
    if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt") {
        var inString = ""
        do {
            inString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        //Write something in file

        let outString = inString + "Date:\(Date()) yd : \(txtStor)\n\n"
        do {
            try outString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope its help